# How to normalize a tiff image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, normalization

I am trying to set some specific pixels inside a image to black, those images are in tiff format, which requires me to decompose them in their respective frames, therefore my tiff image has 50 different frames. For such task, I am using simple values by accessing the pixel index at their given position and simply setting their values to 0. For instance:

```
img[10, 50] = 0
```

every time I try setting their pixels the image goes yellow instantly.

[image]

However, if I remove every line that changes/sets the pixel values to black, the image goes back to normal.

Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image
%pylab inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


image = "myimage.tif"
path = "C:/Dataset/Face1" + image

 plt.imshow(img)
img=mpimg.imread(path)
img[15, 60] = 0
img[15, 85] = 0
img[15, 105] = 0
img[35, 60] = 0
img[35, 85] = 0
img[35, 105] = 0
img[45, 60] = 0
img[43, 75] = 0
img[43, 92] = 0
img[43, 105] = 0
img[58, 55] = 0
img[65, 83] = 0
img[58, 110] = 0
img[75, 83] = 0
img[85, 75] = 0
img[85, 90] = 0
img[90 ,83] = 0
img[95, 60] = 0
img[99, 83] = 0
img[99, 103] = 0
```

I tried normalizing my image the easy way using opencv2:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('image.tif', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
final_img = cv2.normalize(img1,  img1, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

Got this instead:

[image]

How i am decomposing the images

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imagepath = "face1.tif"
path = "C:/Users/images/" + imagepath
img = Image.open(path)

for i in range(50):
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        img.save('C:/Users/images/face1/%s.tif'%(i,))
    except EOFError:
        break
```

What i want to do is normalize the image, when i print the values of one of the lightest pixel, the output is something around 8353. Also, convert it to 8bit image, so i can view it on matplotlib.

Comment: What is a good way to do that? i would like to make sure my image is in 8 bit integer aswell as normalizing their information to 0,255. In opencv it would've been easier, how do i do it in matplotlib?

Comment: @cgohlke i tried: 'imgplot = plt.imshow(img, vmin = 0, vmax= 255)'. Still yellow

Comment: You aren't making it easy for anyone to help you. You say you have a TIFF but don't share it. You say it has multiple frames in it but your code doesn't reflect that. You provide one lump of code that uses `matplotlib` to read it and another based on **OpenCV** - not sure why. For the moment, I can only guess your image(s) is greyscale but you are using the viridis colourmap, so you probably need to add `cmap='gray'` to your plotting command.

Comment: You can maybe use Dropbox, or Google Drive or similar. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, i have edited the question with dropbox links and the code im using for decomposition

Comment: I tried using tifffile and other answers but none of them allows me to change the pixel values and plot my image afterwards. I printed out a pixel value of 8368, how do i normalize it to 0-255? using matplotlib or cv2 will just make the image yellow altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your images use some non-standard encoding scheme. Normally, the pixel values (for a single channel) are bounded to [0..255]. In your case pixel values lie in the range [8162..8383]. `matplotlib` normalizes that range for you automatically. But when you set one of the pixel values to 0, your range becomes [0..8383] and this is the reason why it struggles to display it. Just normalize the data:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread(r'C:\temp\face_1.tif')
img -= img.min() # you can use more sofisticated img = 255*(img - img.min())/(img.max() - img.min())
img[90 ,83] = 0
img[95, 60] = 0
img[99, 83] = 0
img[99, 103] = 0
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

And this will get you:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do proper normalization using Scipy exposure.rescale_intensity() with Python/OpenCV.

In the following, I use OpenCV to read the multi-page TIFF and process the frames in a loop as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure as exposure

# read images
imgs = cv2.imreadmulti("face_1.tif", flags = cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE + cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)[1]

for i,img in enumerate(imgs):
    filename = f"face_1_frame-{i}.png"
    print(f"Processing frame {i} into file {filename}")
    # normalize image to 8-bit range
    img_norm = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
    cv2.imwrite(filename, img_norm)

    # display normalized image
    cv2.imshow('normalized',img_norm)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is the first normalized frame:

[image]